# iOS Safari rounds down Touch pageX/pageY coordinates

Tags: javascript, ios, canvas, safari

I'm drawing on canvas with `touchmove` and I have a strange problem. On iOS `touch.pageX/pageY` always rounded up to integer value, so important fraction is lost and drawing not smooth enough as on other browsers. What can I do about that?

P.S. Canvas scaled up to device pixel ratio with something like this:

```
let styleWidth = window.innerWidth;
let styleHeigth = window.innerHeight;
let canvasWidth =  styleWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
let canvasHeigth = styleHeigth * window.devicePixelRatio;
```

Comment: Not that it will solve your problem , but it's always better to use `( number * ratioNumerator) / ratioDenominator` vs multiplying by floating-point ratio. You will loose FAR less precision upon redrawing due to rescaling of width and/or height.

Comment: Have you tried setting `window.devicePixelRatio = 1`